# How do I get an explicit formula for a geometric sequence with an additional term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have two sequences $a$ and $b$. $a_n$ has a recursive formula that is defined in terms of the previous $a_{n-1}$ in addition to adding the $n$-th term of $b_n$
The formula:

$$
a_n = 2a_{n-1} + b_n
$$

I would like to know how to get an explicit or a direct formula for the $n$-th term of the $a$ sequence, and I am an absolute beginner: I have searched a lot and found things like matrices; however, I got overwhelmed, and I do not know how to approach and/or understand them.

Comment: If you have a recursive formula, you need to know $a_1$. 
Then you just can write down $a_2, a_3, \ldots$ and you will see a pattern.

Comment: $a_n$ could be **anything** depending on $b$.  For example, when $b_n=-2a_{n-1}$ you'll get the $0$-sequence.

Comment: @garondal Yes, I did that, but I did not find the sequence on OEIS or something.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Thanks, but you may assume that $b$ is an arbitrarily defined sequence. A side note: emacs drives me nuts, too. I use vim as my command line editor.

Comment: The point is that you can achieve $a$ to be anything due to the freedom in $b$. So without knowing anything about $b$, it is pointless to ask for an explicit formula for $a$.

Answer (score 2):

This solution only works if $b_n$ is independent of $a_n$ (so that excludes the example given by emacs above). First let $2^n \cdot g_n = a_n $

We then have $$ 2^n \cdot g_n  = 2 \cdot 2^{n-1} \cdot g_{n-1} + b_n$$
Divide by $2^n$ and subtract $g_{n-1}$ from both sides gives $$ \nabla g_{n} = \frac{b_n}{2^n} $$
where $\nabla$ is the [backward finite difference.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)
Then using the identity $$ \sum_{k=a}^b \nabla f(k) = f(b) - f(a-1) $$
one can arrive at $$ g_n = g_0  + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{b_k}{2^k}$$
and finally
$$ a_n = 2^n \left ( a_0  + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{b_k}{2^k} \right )$$

Comment: Thanks for being helpful! I would like to ask a question: what is $g$? or what could I assume it is?

Comment: $g_n$ is defined as $g_n = \frac{a_n}{2^n}$ for convenience of the proof.